# Create copy buttons alert from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new web developer and am working on a quote website project.

I have created a Html page in which there are some quotes with a copy button below all quotes.

You can visit my CodePen to understand the question clearly
https://codepen.io/Akash11166666/pen/JjRzqzp

(***I have displayed copy buttons and quotes from Javascript so you cannot find the elements in HTML.***)

As you can see my CodePen they work perfectly but we cannot know if the text is copied or not. So I need a `<span>Copied</span>` to be visible when each copy button is clicked without inserting the `<span>Copied</span>` to HTML directly, that is from javascript same as copy button was created. They should be so dynamic that for respective copy button the`span` element should be visible and invisible after some seconds.

I have tried numerous way to solve this problem but know of them work although am new to javascript and I don't know much about it.

My CodePen project for reference

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');
let results = [];
const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());
const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
    (pageSize * (page - 1));
const main = async () => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);
  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};
const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}
const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}
const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}
const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}
const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};
const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};
const retrieveAllQuotes = async function () {
  // write your asynchronous fetching here
  return [{
    quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
  },
  {
    quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
  },
  {
    quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
  },
  {
    quotes: "4Love books."
  },
  {
    quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
  },
  {
    quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
  },
  {
    quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
  },
  {
    quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
  },
  {
    quotes: "9Love books."
  },
  {
    quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
  },
  ];
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {
      const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')
        .childNodes[0].textContent;
      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.value = quote;
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand('Copy');
      textArea.remove();
    }
  },
  false
);
main();
```

```css
.mainStatus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.statusHeading {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.latestatus {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 445px;
  min-height: 130px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.allStatus {
  display: flex;
}

.latestatus p {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.copystatus {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /* Main Status */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
  <div class="mainStatus">
    <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
    <div class="allquotes"></div>
    <div class="pagable-status">
      <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
      <div class="pagable-actions">
        <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
        <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
        <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
        <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
        <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
        <select name="page-size">
          <option>20</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
    </div>

    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***Again I would tell my problem that, I need a `<span>Copied</span>` to be visible when each copy button is clicked without inserting the `<span>Copied</span>` to HTML directly, that is from javascript same as copy button was created.***

I hartley thanks for those who answer this question.

Comment: [Same question reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839287/how-to-add-custom-copy-alert-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your button a function `onclick` and whenever it's clicked it will add and remove the `span` after x seconds using `setTimout()`.

Also i have added a `class` on `css` for styling the span but you can always remove it or edit it.

The code i have added was on `js` only was the function `showCopied()` which will create the `element` and add to the `body`. Also added `fade()` and `unfade()` methods which will do the `fade` and `unfade` of the element this 2 methods use `setInterval()`.

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn" onclick="showCopied();">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

function showCopied() {
  let spanCopied = document.createElement('span');
  spanCopied.innerHTML = "Copied!";
  spanCopied.classList.add("spanCopied");
  document.body.appendChild(spanCopied);
  fade(spanCopied);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(spanCopied);
  }, 1400);
}

function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 10);
}

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

            .childNodes[0].textContent;

        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

        textArea.value = quote;

        document.body.appendChild(textArea);

        textArea.select();

        document.execCommand('Copy');

        textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

```css
/* Main Status */
body {
  position: relative;
}
.mainStatus{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 max-width: 95%;
 width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.spanCopied {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.statusHeading{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.latestatus{
 display: grid;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 445px;
 min-height: 130px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.allStatus{
 display: flex;
}
.latestatus p{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.copystatus{
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
}
.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}
.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>
```

More information about `setTimout` can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

More information about setInterval can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a function right after your call to `document.execCommand('Copy')`. Check my snippet below for `showCopied` and CSS class `hasCopied`. This should temporarily show the span and using a `setTimeout` it can be removed after some given time in milliseconds (2000 = 2 seconds).

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return [{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
  ];
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

      const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

        .childNodes[0].textContent;

      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

      textArea.value = quote;

      document.body.appendChild(textArea);

      textArea.select();

      document.execCommand('Copy');

      showCopied();

      textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);

function showCopied() {
  const copiedElement = document.createElement('span');
  copiedElement.innerHTML = "Copied";
  copiedElement.setAttribute("class", "hasCopied");
  resultEl.appendChild(copiedElement);
  setTimeout(() => {
    resultEl.removeChild(copiedElement);
  }, 2000);
}

main();
```

```css
/* Main Status */

.mainStatus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.statusHeading {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.latestatus {
  display: grid;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 445px;
  min-height: 130px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.allStatus {
  display: flex;
}

.latestatus p {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.copystatus {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}

.hasCopied {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <a href="hindinj.html">caeman</a>
  <div class="mainStatus">
    <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
    <div class="allquotes"></div>
    <div class="pagable-status">
      <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
      <div class="pagable-actions">
        <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
        <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
        <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
        <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
        <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
        <select name="page-size">
          <option>20</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```